# Generating Spatial White Noise audio in Python

Tags: python, audio

I'm training a neural network on stimuli which are being developed to mimic a sensory neuroscience task to compare performance to human results.

The task is based on spatial localization of audio. I need to generate white noise audio in python to present to the neural network, but also need to alter the audio as if it were presented at different locations. I understand how I'd generate the audio, but I'm not sure on how to generate the white noise from different theoretical locations.

Comment: several libraries like OpenAL provide ability to render audio in 3D where you control either / or the 3D location of the source audio and / or 3D location of the listener ... dunno if it also provides positioning of the pair or ~~ears~~  which brings up the question :  is speed of sound slow enough and is the acoustic neuroscience processing audio fast enough to warrant not only positioning in 3D space but also the audio phase values as the audio waves propagate across space ... meaning does biology leverage sussing out phase differences btw ears of given source audio ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a delay to the right or left track, to account for the arrival time at the two ears. If I recall correctly, it amounts to up to about 25 or 30 milliseconds, depending on the angle. The travel distance disparity from source to the two ears can be calculated with basic trigonometry, and then multiplied by speed of sound in air to get the delay length. (IDK what python has for controlling delays or to what granularity delay lengths can be specified.)

Most of the other cues we have for spacial location are a lot harder to quantify. Most commonly we use volume, of course. Especially for higher-pitched content (wavelengths smaller than the width of the head) the head itself can block and cause some volume differences, based on the angle.

But a lot comes from reverberation for environmental cues, from timbrel roll-off as a function of distance (a quiet sound with lots of highs in the mix can really sound like they are right next to your ear), from moving the head to capture the sound from different angles, and from the filtering effects of the pinna of the ear. Because everyone's ear shape is different, I don't know that there is a universal thumbnail algorithm for what causes a sound to be sensed as originating from a particular altitude for a given angle. I think to some extent we just all learn by experiencing the sounds with our own particular ears while observing the sound source visually.

Comment: To add to that, because we only have two ears, we can theoretically only localise when something is located in a specific cone by just the timings. In practice there are other factors, such as ear shape and contextual clues. For more info I highly recommend [this video](https://youtu.be/CqB95rj_txI) by Steve Mould.